# Handling error after aggregation

Tags: error-handling, apache-camel, aggregation

I am reading some lines from a CSV file, converting them to business objects, aggregating  these to batches and passing the resulting aggregates to a bean, which may throw an `PersistenceException`.
Somehow like this:
`from(file:inputdir).split().tokenize("\n").bean(a).aggregate(constant(true), new AbstractListAggregationStrategy(){...}).completionSize(3).bean(b)`

I have a `onException(Exception.class).handled(true).to("file:failuredir").log()`. If an exception occurs on `bean(a)`, everything is handled as expected: wrong lines in `inputdir/input.csv` are written to `failuredir/input.csv`.
Now if `bean(b)` fails, Camel seems to fail reconstructing the original message:

```
message.org.apache.camel.component.file.GenericFileOperationFailedException: Cannot store file: target/failure/ID-myhostname-34516-1372093690069-0-7
```

Having tried various attempts to get this working, like using HawtDBAggregationRepository, toggling `useOriginalMessage` at `onException` and propagating back the exception in my AggregationStrategy, I am out of ideas.

How can I achieve the same behaviour for `bean(b)` which can be seen with `bean(a)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The aggregator is a stateful EIP pattern, so when it sends out a message, then its a new Exchange. So the bean(b) cannot get access to the original message that came from the file route.